# Audacity Recording volume too low

Tags: audio-recording, equipment, audacity, gain

I've been using an AT2020 USB directly into my 2015 macbook Pro retina and recording in Audacity. I recently wanted to upgrade to a nicer mic. Every mic I try, the volume is super low. Increasing the gain also increases the noise floor to an untenable level. There is one exception, the Rode NT-1 condenser mic seems to work fine, but I want to use another mic and I can't figure out what is happening. When I say quiet, I mean the waveform is small -- the signal strength is not strong.

Here's the setups I've tried:

RodeNT-1 > XLR > MobilePre USB preamp > MBPro > Audacity (seems ok, but still a little quiet)

Shure 87b XLR > MobilePre USB preamp > MBPro > Audacity (very quiet)

Shure SM7b XLR > MobilePre USB preamp > MBPro > Audacity (very quiet)

Shure 87b > XLR > phant. power supply > XLR > apogee duet > MBPro > Audacity (very quiet)

RodeNT-1 > XLR > phant. power supply > XLR > apogee duet > MBPro > Audacity (very quiet)

Shure 87b > XLR > phant. power supply > XLR > Sapphire preamp > MBPro > Audacity (very quiet)

RodeNT-1 > XLR > phant. power supply > XLR > Sapphire preamp > MBPro > Audacity (very quiet)

When I switch back to the AT2020USB, everything works fine.

The mics, XLRs, Sapphire, power supply and macbook pro were all brand new. I also tried these setups in different rooms, different locations and at different times. Audacity is the most recent version. I had the computer running on battery as well as plugged in, and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any help is appreciated. I can't find anyone else really having the same issues, but I've eliminated everything but Audacity as the issue. I really want to keep using it though.

Comment: You do have the mic gains set up correctly, right? – Of course the SM7b is a dynamic mic and hence weaker, but the others are all condensers and should definitely be able to drive your preamps into _overdrive_ if you crank up the gain. If that doesn't happen, the problem has nothing to do with the computer; perhaps it's just that the cables are broken (sometimes even new leads are rubbish)!